# Select radio button by default using Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Preselecting a radio button in twitter's bootstrap without using jquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
     <label class="btn btn-primary active">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="athletebutton" value="1" checked> Athlete  </label>

      <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="coachbutton"> Coach </label>
  </div>
```

Mark the label class with `active`

See screenshots & video here:

Video:http://d.pr/v/b3Gm

Screenshot:

[image]